# How to prepopulate images from database in loop using jquery on edit page?

Tags: jquery, laravel

How do i prepopulate my gallery images from database into here in jquery? I was wondering how could i inject my laravel loop into jquery?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-images">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
    *Jquery*
    <script>
        let preloaded = [{
            id: 1,
                src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=1'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=2'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=3'
            },
        ];
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.input-images').imageUploader({
                preloaded: preloaded,
                imagesInputName: 'gallery',
                preloadedInputName: 'old',
                maxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
                maxFiles: 12
            });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: I've updated your question a bit to hopefully get you some friendly eyeballs on your question.  It's still not clear what's not happening here.  Are you getting an error?  If so, edit your question to inlcude the full error message.  If no error message, what do you think is blocking your progress?

Answer (score 0):

To get the laravel object inside the Javascript code, you can use the `@json($object)` method.

Example:

Your Controller:

```php
class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $images = Image::all();
        $images = $images->map(function($img){
            $img->url = asset($img->url);
            return $img;
        });

        return view('gallery.edit', ['images' => $images] );
    }
}
```

Your JS Code:

```js
var images = @json($images);
```

Then you can use the `images` variable just like a JS array.

Comment: it works but show the blank image holder, seems image path is not coming. how could i acheiive passing id, and image source like: let preloaded = [
    {id: 1, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=1'},
    {id: 2, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=2'},
    {id: 3, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=3'},
    {id: 4, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=4'},
    {id: 5, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=5'},
    {id: 6, src: 'https://picsum.photos/500/500?random=6'},
];

Comment: Yes. That can happen. You can set the correct path with eloquent's map method and `asset()` method prior to passing it to the blade view.

Comment: I am sorry i did not follow this, could you please how exactly it could be done. thanks

Comment: I mean before sending the values to the frontend, you can set the correct URLs in the controller method by using the eloquent model's map method and the `asset()` helper method. I updated the code with an example. You can follow a similar procedure